# how do I persist postgresql data in docker-compose?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

In the past, I created a `docker-compose.yml` that has a postgres database with adminer, and I persisted the data to a local directory. I have just tried to do that again, but I receive an error saying:

```
initdb: error: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty
initdb: hint: If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty the directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" or run initdb with an argument other than "/var/lib/postgresql/data".
```

So this says that there is something already in the container's data storage directory despite it being a fresh container. But because I didn't get this before it seems like there was a change with the docker image, although I am just guessing from the message. How can I resolve this now? I would just like to have a docker postgres running that will persist whatever data I add to it. Here is my compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pgpassword
      POSTGRES_DB: my_db
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "my_db", "-U"]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
    volumes:
        - ./db/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Comment: The right-hand side of `volumes:` [needs to be](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#where-to-store-data) `/var/lib/postgresql/data`, not a subdirectory (unless you redefine `$PGDATA`, but that's not usually necessary).

Comment: Doh, thanks! I must have done something to my old file in the meantime.